# Random 700% increase on a website hit

Tags: traffic, botattack, web-traffic, high-traffic

I have a website with a domain that has been registered for around 10 years now 
the website used to get daily traffic of around 400 to 500 hits per day - but for the past 4 weeks the website users have increased to 6-8k per day from 400-500

The current average session duration is ~17seconds - bounce rate ~42% 
compare to average session duration of ~30 seconds and 80% bounce rate

I have no doubt that traffic is generated from bots - and am thinking it's coming from the business competitors

Should I be worried about this?

Any advice will be highly appreciated

Comment: Without sample log file entries, we cannot know what is happening, but clearly, as you mention, something is and I would be concerned. Without further information, I am not sure we can really help. Can you give us some samples out of your log files? As well, let us know something about your configuration. I would be quickly shutting down this traffic if it appears to be useless. I would be blocking any traffic from non-subscriber blocks. These are not users. Cheers!!

Comment: See also: [Spike in direct traffic - how to prevent bots](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116364/spike-in-direct-traffic-how-to-prevent-bots) and [Exceptional spike in traffic: can Google Analytics help to know the reason?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109468/exceptional-spike-in-traffic-can-google-analytics-help-to-know-the-reason)

Comment: Also, there are security applications that can be installed on the web server. Fail2ban seems to be very popular and allows for customization. https://www.fail2ban.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can move your website to Cloudflare DNS, and let Cloudflare DNS handle the bots and it's detection.

The free plan of Cloudflare can do the job.

Peace of mind for sure.

Good luck.